# Definition of Single-channel or Multi-channel arrays in opencv

Tags: java, arrays, opencv

Hi to all of you my friends. First of all , i already know java so i think i'll stick to that but anyways. I'm creating a facial recognition program and I'm just starting with opencv. I'm learning the Class "Mat" and what it means, here's the definition.

> The class Mat represents an n-dimensional dense numerical single-channel or multi-channel array. It can be used to store real or complex-valued vectors and matrices, grayscale or color images, voxel volumes, vector fields, point clouds, tensors, histograms.

I'm trying to learn what a single-channel or multi-channel array mean but i can't find information online for whatever reason. Can you explain this concept to me maybe linking some useful websites?

Thank you, Mattia (aka DJack)

Comment: Number of channels means, how many values are used to represent a single element (e.g. pixel in a picture). For example, grayscale image represents each pixel by 1 value (intensity), so it will be stored as a single channel `Mat`. RGB image needs 3 values (red, green and blue), hence it needs a 3 channel `Mat`. RGBA has 4 values per pixel, so 4 channel image.

Comment: and so, can you link me some information online because I can only manage to find information about "micro"arrays (About single-channel and multi-channel)

Comment: Not sure where to point you at, I'm talking from experience. It's all about abstraction. At the bottom, there's just a linear array of values. Since OpenCV is mostly about image processing, and we consider images 2-dimensional, it's more convenient to abstract an image as a 2d array of vectors.

Comment: Example of the convenience -- changing from RGB to grayscale. Size stays the same (2 dimensions), only the channel count changes.

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://docs.opencv.org/master/db/da5/tutorial_how_to_scan_images.html#tutorial_how_to_scan_images_storing

Comment: oh, ok, now i understand it, thank you a lot!

Answer (score 2):

single-channel or multi-channel can be understood by simple daily life examples.
Suppose you have two rectangular-shaped slices of bread.

Put the first bread on the floor in a vertical way(standing bread on the side).
And look from the top, the thing you will find is the single channel.

again, put the second piece of bread in the same way but parallel to the first bread ( parallel in the horizontal plane).

Now again look from the top, you will see two pieces of bread this time, this represents 2 channel matrix.

[click on this link to see an image which is a 3 channel matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rSyTo.png)

This is a 3 channel 8 bit unsigned integer.
This array consists of tuples with 3 elements.
For example :
{54,0.34} - first tuple
{58,78,185} - second tuple and so on.
but in the single channel matrix, you will get only one element. like 58, 78 etc.

Answer (score 0):

Directly from the comment by @Dan Mašek solves your problem:

**Number of channels** means:

> how many values are used to represent a single element (e.g. pixel in a picture). For example, grayscale image represents each pixel by 1 value (intensity), so it will be stored as a single channel Mat. RGB image needs 3 values (red, green and blue), hence it needs a 3 channel Mat. RGBA has 4 values per pixel, so 4 channel image.